# How I replace values in HTML attributes via config.json file with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-cheerio

Let's say I have a JSON file with the pairs:

```
{
  "Table":{
    "fullwidth": "680",
    "color": "#33d025",
    "margin1": "30",
    "margin2": "60",
    "padding": "20"
  }
}
```

then, I want to read those values and use them to replace attributes in an html file that looks like this:

```
<table width="{{Table.fullwidth}}" bgcolor="{{Table.color}}" style="margin: {{Table.margin1}}px {{Table.margin2}}px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: {{Table.padding}}px;">
      <img src="a.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, with the html file in a "temp/" path, after gulping, I obtain a valid html file in "dist/" with the attributes changed looking like this:

```
<table width="680" bgcolor="#33d025" style="margin: 30px 60px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 20px;">
      <img src="a.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have already tried gulp-token-replace but after running it once, it won't work again if I save new values in the json file, even when it triggers the watch function, forcing me to restart the "gulp".

Is there a gulp plugin that can do this? or a technique that can replace the gulp-token-replace?

Maybe just javascript, but, can I run something like that from inside a gulp process (running watch to refresh it)?

Gulpfile.js as requested:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'),

// Include plugins
fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
images = require('gulp-imagemin'),
cache = require('gulp-cache'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
reload = browserSync.reload,
runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
del = require('del'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
gtr = require('gulp-token-replace')

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function (cb) {
runSequence('clean', ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'watch'], cb);
});

// TASKS

// Clean 'dist'
gulp.task('clean', function () {
return del(['HTMLTemplates/*.html', 'HTMLTemplates/img', 'Temp/*.html']);
});

// Compress images
gulp.task('BB', function () {
gulp.src('templates/img/*.{gif,jpg,png}')
    .pipe(cache(images({
        optimizationLevel: 4,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Templates/img/'));
});

// Reload browser
gulp.task('reload', function () {
browserSync.reload();
});

// Prepare Browser-sync
gulp.task('CC', ['AA'], function () {
browserSync.init({
    // browserSync.init(['templates/*/*.html'], {
    //proxy: 'your_dev_site.url'
    server: {
        baseDir: './HTMLTemplates'
    }
});
});

// MAIN TASKS

gulp.task('AA', function (cbk) {
runSequence('fileinclude', 'trp', cbk);
});

// Force to run fileinclude first before replacing the tokens
gulp.task('trp', ['fileinclude'], function (done) {
function onFinish(event) {
    if (event.task === 'tokenreplace') {
        gulp.removeListener('task_stop', onFinish);
        done();
    }
}
gulp.on('task_stop', onFinish);
gulp.start('tokenreplace');
});

// Include partial files into email template (fileinclude)
gulp.task('fileinclude', function () {
// grab 'template'
return gulp.src('templates/layouts/*.tpl.html')
    // include partials
    .pipe(fileinclude({
        basepath: 'templates/components/'
    }))
    // remove .tpl.html extension name
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: ""
    }))
    // add new extension name
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: ".html"
    }))
    // move file to folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Temp/'))
    .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Template file includes complete'
    }));
});

// Replace tokens in the index.html created by fileinclude
gulp.task('tokenreplace', ['fileinclude'], function (doit) {
var config = require('./templates/components/000 vars/config.json');
return gulp.src('Temp/index.html')
    .pipe(gtr({
        global: config
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('HTMLTemplates/'))
    // notify to say the task has complete
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Vars includes complete'
    })), doit();
});

// END of MAIN TASKS

// WATCH

// Watch files for changes in html/css/tpl.html/images
gulp.task('watch', function () {
gulp.watch(['templates/components/**/*.html'], ['AA']);
gulp.watch(['templates/components/**/*.css'], ['AA']);
gulp.watch(['templates/layouts/*.tpl.html'], ['AA']);
gulp.watch(['templates/components/000 vars/*.json'], ['trp']);
gulp.watch(['HTMLTemplates/*.html'], ['reload']);
gulp.watch('templates/img/*', ['BB']);
});
```

Comment: The note just indicates you can't use regex to find values to be replaced.  Some plugins can use regexps.  So that is not your problem.  We would need to see your gulpfile.js as well to help.  I see no reason why gulp-token-replace couldn't be used in a task with a watcher.

Comment: @mark Gulp-token-replace works, the problem is that after the first run (reading the config.json file with the set of vars) it does not re-load the config.json file. So, the whole process is triggered but the vars stay the same. I'm going to add the gulpfile.js so it gets clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer directly from the developer of the Gulp Token Replace plugin, so I'm answering my own question for archive purposes.

Replace this:

```
// Replace tokens in the index.html created by fileinclude
gulp.task('tokenreplace', ['fileinclude'], function (doit) {
  var config = require('./templates/components/000 vars/config.json');
  return gulp.src('Temp/index.html')
  .pipe(gtr({
  global: config
}))
```

with this:

```
// Replace tokens in the index.html created by fileinclude
gulp.task('tokenreplace', ['fileinclude'], function (doit) {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./templates/components/000 vars/config.json')]
  var config = require('./templates/components/000 vars/config.json');
  return gulp.src('Temp/index.html')
  .pipe(gtr({
  global: config
}))
```

And now it works like a charm!